# Swift 4: How can I make the keyboard always appear and never disappear?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4

Question: I am wondering how can I make the keyboard always stay on the page and not disappear?

This is my code below so far:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    textField1?.becomeFirstResponder()
    numberKeyPadPopUp()
    textField1.delegate = self

}
```

Answer (score 5):

1- Don't implement this method

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return true
}
```

2- Don't write any of these lines anywhere

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()

self.view.endEditing(true)
```

And the keyboard will stay up